# Not sure with partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. Earlier I had Ubuntu on HDD but today I've got SSD and decided to install it on it. I had 120GB for Ubuntu on SSD and ~250GB on HDD(due to Windows OS as the second one). I had no clue about partition, so I did next: / folder on SSD and /home on HDD(no swap cuz I think 12GB RAM is sufficient for me). After installing I found out that that it might be not so good to install / folder on SSD, so now I'm a bit confused about it whether I did everything OK or not. Can anyone give me a bit of advice about my partition and, in case it's not great, help me with the good partition without reinstalling Ubuntu. Thanks for any help and sorry for kinda silly and newbie question!

Comment: If you have the root partition in SSD, it's better because the OS can run faster and it wont cause any problems.

Comment: @MitKan, Thank you! And what about some folders, such as /var? I've heard it can harm SSD.

Comment: It wont cause any problems either with the /var. I have 4 partitions on my laptop for Ubuntu (dual boot) with SSD and I have no problems..

Comment: @MitKan Thank you for response!